# Merging two df to form one using certain conditions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In spark python I have to merge two dataframes having same column name and type:
When merging dataframes few conditions are present:

1. If `UPDATE_TYPE` is update ignore all values from that row other than `DISPOSITION` and `TIME`.
   For disposition use value of disposition from that row (update type is update).
   For Time use greater value of time from both rows
2. If `UPDATE_TYPE` is not `UPDATE` keep all values from table two other than time. For time use greater value of time.

I have done it but using reducebykey. It is a very slow solution. Can I use df directly and do it?

```
df1
ID      UPDATE_TYPE TIME DISPOSITION ROG
1       SEGMENT     1000 null        Q
2       SEGMENT     1001 value       W
3       SEGMENT     1002 null        E
3       UPDATE      1004 some_value  A
4       SEGMENT     1003 null        R
5       SEGMENT     1004 value_old   T  
7       SEGMENT     1050 value       U

df2
ID      UPDATE_TYPE TIME DISPOSITION ROG
4       SEGMENT     1003 value        P1
5       UPDATE      1015 value_new    P2
6       SEGMENT     1010 value        P3
```

```
Final output
df_output
ID      UPDATE_TYPE TIME DISPOSITION ROG
1       SEGMENT     1000 null        Q
2       SEGMENT     1001 value       W
3       SEGMENT     1004 some_value  E
4       SEGMENT     1003 null        P1
5       SEGMENT     1015 value_new   T  
6       SEGMENT     1010 value       P3
7       SEGMENT     1050 value       U
```

**EDIT**
It turns out duplicate ids can exist in table one itself. These duplicate ID's must not appear in final output

Comment: Use `df1.join(df2, Seq("ID"), "left").select(<use case when then>)`

Answer (score 1):

you could try spark sql:

```
SELECT 
DF1.ID,
DF1.UPDATE_TYPE,
CASE WHEN DF1.TIME > DF2.TIME THEN DF1.TIME ELSE DF2.TIME END AS TIME,
CASE WHEN DF2.UPDATE_TYPE='SEGMENT' THEN DF1.DISPOSITION ELSE DF2.DISPOSITION END AS DISPOSITION,
CASE WHEN DF2.UPDATE_TYPE='SEGMENT' THEN DF2.ROG ELSE DF1.ROG END AS ROG
FROM 
DF1 LEFT JOIN DF2 ON DF1.ID = DF2.ID
```

Comment: Hi @chlebek, I forgot to mention that I need data from both the tables. So may be full outer join but will rest of the things remain same?

Comment: I have updated the scenario a littlebit. It is possible that all the mentioned conditions above exists in table one itslef.

Comment: To achieve it you could try to cross join df1 with itself and put distinct keyword after select: `SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM DF1 CROSS JOIN DF1 ...`  but I didn't tested if it work